# Talend : tmap Nullpointer exception while merging two CSV files

Tags: java, file, talend

I want to merge two CSV files. The problem that I am facing is one of the two CSV files has dynamic column.

e.g.

The first CSV file has two column. A and G. Column G has comma separated values.

```
A | G       |<-Column Names
--|---------|
A1| G1,G2,G3| <-Row
A2| G2,G5,G6|<-Row
```

[image: MainCSv]

The second CSV file has dynamic columns. But it will alwas have the column A(uid). e.g.

```
A | C1    |C2       |Othercolumns|<-Column Names
--|-------|---------|------------|
A1|C1Value|C2Value  |            |<-Row
A2|C1Value| C2Value |            |<-Row
```

[image: Lookup CSV]

I want to merge these two files So the output will be:

```
A |G          | C1    |C2       |Othercolumns|<-Column Names
--|-----------|-------|---------|------------|
A1| G1,G2,G3  |C1Value|C2Value  |            |<-Row
A2| G2,G5,G6  |C1Value| C2Value |            |<-Row
```

[image]

Here is the job.

[image]

I didn't check the include header option in tfileoutputdelimited_1.
This merges the csv files correctly, but does not bring the column information of 2nd CSV file(one with dynamic column). The output is as shown below.

```
A |G          |       |         |            |
--|-----------|-------|---------|------------|
A1| G1,G2,G3  |C1Value|C2Value  |            |<-Row
A2| G2,G5,G6  |C1Value| C2Value |            |<-Row
```

To get the column names, When I check the "include Header" option in the output file I get the below exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at routines.system.DynamicUtils.writeHeaderToDelimitedFile(DynamicUtils.java:72)
at content.csvmergetest_0_1.CSVMergeTest.tFileInputDelimited_2Process(CSVMergeTest.java:2696)
at content.csvmergetest_0_1.CSVMergeTest.runJobInTOS(CSVMergeTest.java:3109)
at content.csvmergetest_0_1.CSVMergeTest.main(CSVMergeTest.java:2975)
```

As shown below, In this case only one row is fetched from the Tfileinputdelimited_2. I guess that row is the header column and that is why the nullpointer exception.
[image]

Why is this happening? How will I get the headers?
Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: I think you crushed in a bug, since you have not control on how to write headers to file. I cannot be sure since I don't own a copy of TIS/paid edition, so I cannot reproduce. Have you already tried to save the table on a test database? Just to look at on what's going on? Anyway AFAIK when using dynamic schemas you can only have one column (the dynamic one) in your schema definitions. But as I said, I cannot test :(

Comment: Funnily enough I've literally just built something that I realised could use this exact functionality, however it worked fine for me. Can you check that all of the columns that are in your dynamic column set actually have a header? Otherwise I'm guessing the header is set to null and then the method that writes dynamic data to a delimited file requires a non null header.

Comment: All the columns have header.Why is tfileInputDelimited_2 fetching a single row when I set include header to true?

Comment: Can you edit into your question some screenshots of the configuration of the 2 tFileInputDelimited components?

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file with the "othercolumns" as 1 column of type Dynamic.
[image]

Before joining in tMap you need to extract the A column from it:
[image]

Then take care to only have one dynamic type in the output schema, because talend cannot handle two.
[image]

The resultfile including one header line and 1 "othercolumns" colum Z looks as follows:

```
A;G;C1;C2;Z
A1;G1,G2,G3;C1Value;C2Value;Z1
A2;G2,G5,G6;C1Value;C2Value;Z2
```